# Dask + pyinstaller fails

Tags: python, runtime-error, pyinstaller, dask

I am trying to use dask dataframes into a packaged executable using pyinstaller.

I have just

`import dask`

in my executable and I package it with

`pyinstaller scripts.py`

When I run it I get that `/some/path/dask.yaml` is not found.

Does somebody know if there are hidden imports that I should add or how else to solve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For using `dask` with PyInstaller you need to add `dask.yaml` and `distributed.yaml` to your output executable with [`add-data`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files) flag:

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data "<python_path>/Lib/site-packages/dask/dask.yaml;./dask" --add-data "<python_path>/Lib/site-packages/distributed/distributed.yaml;./distributed" script.py
```

Comment: This is a bit sad really, isn't it? There could be any number of miscellaneous files in your dependencies that you don't notice aren't included until you hit a particular code path?

Comment: @UtterlyConfused Some Python modules don't build with the only Python and they may have other dependencies. But I think it is not a big deal to provide them manually.

Comment: I created a bug report for this issue https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/6634

Comment: @Korijn I think this is not a Dask problem. It would be better to report it on [PyInstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues).

Comment: I have used `pyjanitor` library in my code and get the error that `some path distributed/distributed.yaml` file is not available. This answer reall helpful for me to build my pyinstaller command as `pyinstaller -F --add-data "D:/Users/username/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/distributed/distributed.yaml;./distributed" --onefile --windowed test.py`

Answer (score 0):

If `dask` is installed in `<python_path>\Lib\site-packages\theano`, you need to create a hook-dask.py file with this content:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import get_package_paths
datas = [(get_package_paths('dask')[1],"dask"),]
```

and copy this file into your PyInstaller folder:

Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks

When you run pyinstaller, you need to add the path of `site-packages` with the -p option:

```
pyinstaller myApp.py -p <python_path>\Lib\site-packages
```

It will copy the entire dask folder into your dist output folder.